# VS 2013 remote debugging attaches as v2.0 instead of v4.0

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, I've got a .NET 4.5 project configured for remote debugging.  When I hit F5, the debugger attaches to the remote debug monitor on the remote machine (Windows 7 x64) and launches the application (also x64).  However, I get no output in the debug window and breakpoints aren't hit.  If I launch the application manually and then attach to the remote process, I get debug output and can hit breakpoints.

Looking more carefully, I discovered that when I hit F5 and then go to the attach process dialog, the process is currently attached for debugging managed code for 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5.  It should be attached for debugging managed code for 4.0 and 4.5, so that's obviously why I'm not getting any output or hitting any break points. When I manually run launch the process and then attach, it correctly attaches as 4.0/4.5.  So the question is, how do I get VS 2013 to attach correctly (for debugging managed 4.0 and 4.5 code) when hitting F5?

Also of interest, I don't have this problem when running the application as 32-bit on 32-bit Windows 7, nor or as a 32-bit or 64-bit app on 64-bit Windows 8.

My development machine in Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 1.  The application is an Outlook add-in.  In the C# project properties debug tab, "Use remote machine" is checked with the name of the remote machine.  "Start action" is set to "Start external program" with the path to Outlook set (as it exists on the remote machine).

Comment: Can you share the details on how the project is setup for remote debugging?  I think the key is in there

Comment: @JaredPar, I edited the question to add the details.